# Jenkins - Master Strategy for Prod & Non-Prod Environments

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get a CI/CD pipeline going, my problem arises from having to create separate Jenkins instances of Prod and Non-Prod environments.

My CI/CD setup is pretty basic, I use a jenkinsfile with a series of standard steps, that are automatically triggered by pull request approvals on develop or master branches. Now if we go with 2 separate Jenkins masters, one per environment, how can the pipeline still work? So basically, when pull requests are approved on develop branch, Jenkinsfile executes a bunch of steps (test-build-archive artifact) on Non-Prod Jenkins Master and when pull requests are approved on master branch, Jenkinsfile executes steps(promote archived artifact to prod) on Prod Jenkins Master.

Comment: Why do you have to have separate Jenkins instances for the different environments? Also what's the specific problem with getting them to track a particular branch?

Comment: This is for Security, I am told. To prevent a single Jenkins instance from talking to both prod and non-prod systems and being open to internet (maven repos, NIST vulnerability databases, updating plugins etc.). This separate prod Jenkins will then be blocked from internet and only have access to Nexus to download artifact and promote to production servers.